# Sublime Build System for Gradle

Tags: build, gradle, sublimetext2

I want to have a custom build system but am really not able to make one. I have Gradle 1.2 installed and even the `GRADLE_HOME` is set correctly now I have the following commend in the build system file

```
{
   "cmd": ["gradle","build.gradle"],
   "path": "$project"
}
```

And the error I get is as follows (when I try to build my project):

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'gradle', u'build.gradle']]
[dir:  /home/roger/Project/Visage/HelloWorld/src/main/visage/visage/javafx]
[path: $project]
[Finished]
```

Actually my Project Base directory is `HelloWorld` and I have my `build.gradle` there itself. Please help me to write the correct build system or give the correct commands to avoid error and execute successfully. I am currently using `UBUNTU 12.04`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you have to use a shell for your build system. and instead of path I guess you mean "working_dir". can you try this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["gradle"],
    "shell": "true",
    "working_dir": "${project_path}"
}
```

cheers,

René

Comment: This atleast seems to trigger my Gradle. I am not able to try it out here at my workplace due to proxy settings stuff. But ll update you asap.

Comment: for quiet builds, use `"cmd": ["gradle", "-q"],`

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter Gradle configuration in Sublime Text 3:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "gradle",
    "working_dir": "${project_path}"
}
```

Go to menu 'Tools > Build System > New Build System...' and paste this text. Then save the configuration file as 'Gradle.sublime-build'.